# Wait with q.defer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I suffer with this problem for a long time.

When starting app i'm get some data

```
setGetFactory.getData('server/getTest.php','q').then(function(data){
        questionsFactory.loadTest(data);
});
```

The received data I transfer to the function of the factory which processes them

```
service.loadTest = function (data) {
       startQuestionList = data;
       questionList = angular.copy(startQuestionList);
};
```

I also have a function that should give data to the controller. But the problem is that when the controller calls it, the data is not received yet.

```
 service.getTest  = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        defer.resolve(questionList);
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

I try to solve the problem this way - but it does not help.
How can I expect in a function, while the variable will cease to be undefined()

if I change the function of getting something like this

```
service.getTest  = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        setTimeout(function () {
            defer.resolve(questionList);
        },1000);
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

Everything will work, but I do not want to wait for the sparse time ...

Comment: What is `getData`? Why does it resolve before the data is ready?

Comment: @Bergi that is a method factory. It dosn't resolve before data ready

Comment: Ah, right. Your problem is the `questionList =` assignment to the global variable. Don't do that - it happens asynchronously and you can never know whether/when it can be used! If you need a global storage, store a promise there. Or just return the `getData` promise directly.

Comment: @Bergi

I realized that I'm problematic in a global variable, but I did not understand how to solve it. Can you give at least a small example?

Comment: @Bergi
now I declare it them so
`mainApp.factory('questionsFactory',function ($q) {
   var service = {},questionList,startQuestionList;`

Comment: Please show where `getTest` and/or `questionList` are *used* in your application. That's the part that needs to change into using a promise

Comment: @Bergi
getTest i using intro my controller to get question list,that using to ng-repeat.
`mainApp.controller('questionsCtrl',function (setGetFactory,questionsFactory,answersFactory) {
    var questions  = this;

    questionsFactory.getTest().then(function (data) {
        questions.test = data;
    });`

Comment: getTest at factory i show before.

Comment: Is `getTest` called multiple times? If not, then it should just return the `getData` promise directly.

Comment: Where is `questions.test` used afterwards? Does that code know that it's asynchronously initialised?

Comment: getTest called only one time,
code doesnt'now

Comment: So change `service.getTest` to `return setGetFactory.getData('server/getTest.php','q').then(angular.copy);`. That's it. Remove all `loadTest` stuff.

Comment: @Bergi
it almost solved my problem, but added a new one.
I must be able to work with the information received. For example, delete one of the objects.
And now it is wrapped $$state. 
getTest now
   `service.getTest  = function () {
        questionList = setGetFactory.getData('server/getTest.php',{type:'Questions'}).then(angular.copy);
        return questionList;
    };`

Comment: i must can do like that
`service.deleteQuestion = function (id) {
       _.remove(questionList,{id:id})
   };`

Comment: [link](https://hkar.ru/R1D4)
that i have in factory and in controller

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to sync your promises ie. `service.loadTest` with `service.getTest`
like this

```
service.loadTest = function (data) {
   var defer = $q.defer();
   startQuestionList = data;
   questionList = angular.copy(startQuestionList);
   defer.resolve(questionList);
   return defer.promise;    
};
```

And then while calling  you need to do this way

```
    setGetFactory.getData('server/getTest.php','q').then(function(data){
        questionsFactory.loadTest(data).then(function(questionList){
          setGetFactory.getTest(questionList).then(function(){
               //this way all the steps take place on after another
          });
    });
});
```

You can pass questionList  as a parameter and use it in `getTest()`

In this case what happens is;
First, your getData promise is resolved then comes the turn of your loadTest and then comes the turn of your getTest() function so all these functions will be called one after other as per the hierarchy and in a synchronous way.

Comment: You don't need that `loadTest` at all if you move the callback inside there

Comment: @Bergi
i don't understend
The method of control that causes the effect will probably clarify the situation

questionsFactory.getTest().then(function (data) {
        questions.test = data;
    });

Comment: I'm just giving an example how to get promise inside promise working.The OP can modify as per his need.

Comment: @BlackMamba
Probably l'm not correct discribe the task.
I gave clarification in the comment above

Comment: I've added the clarification to my answer see if it helps

Comment: @BlackMamba
Perhaps I do not quite understand the method getTest should return the value questionList to the controller that caused it.
In the event that this value is not yet declared the method must promise the controller that it will return it.
The difficulty is that the controller calls this method immediately when the application starts.
I do not understand how to apply your help in my situation.

Comment: When do you want to call the function